# Sendgrid - how to automatically send an email once a user is subscribing to a list

Tags: shopify, sendgrid

I have a Shopify store with Sendgrid integration.
I have installed the Sendgrid newsletter subscription on the site.
Now what I want is to automatically trigger an email to the subscribers once they subscribe to a list.

Any idea how can this be done?

thanks!

Comment: please read http://www.triggeredmessaging.com/supported-esps/sendgrid

Comment: i don t see how i can trigger the mail on user subscription to newsletter.

Comment: Could you explain further how you installed the SendGrid Newsletter Subscription on the site? Did you use the SendGrid Subscription Widget, from SendGrid.com or did you do it from some Shopify backend?